# how to validate a textfieldfom widget of a form in which there are 5 textfieldfom widget ,one by one in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to validate a text field in the form,and showing alert if it is empty.

My problem is that all the fields are validating at the same time, but I need  one field to validate at a time

My current code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main(){
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new App(),
  ));
}
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _name,_last,_add;
  var alert;
 m(){
   if(_name.isEmpty){
     showDialog(context: context,
         child: new AlertDialog(
           title: new Text('name'),
         ));
   }
   else if(_last.isEmpty){

     showDialog(context: context,
         child: new AlertDialog(
           title: new Text('last'),
         ));
   }
   else {
       showDialog(context: context,
           child: new AlertDialog(
             title: new Text('add'),
           ));
   }
 }


  pressed() {
    var form = formkey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: new Form(
        key: formkey,
          child: new ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text('name'),
              new TextFormField(
                validator: (str){
                  return str.isEmpty?m():null;
                },
              ),
              new Text('last'),
              new TextFormField(
                validator: (str){
                  return str.isEmpty? m():null;
                },
              ),
              new Text('add'),
              new TextFormField(
                validator: (str){
                  return str.isEmpty?m():null;
                },
              ),
              new RaisedButton(onPressed: pressed)
            ],
          )
        ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things to point out. First, the validator is expecting a string to be returned so that it can display an error message below the field, but you are calling a method m() that returns nothing. See [validator documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FormField/validator.html). For example:

```
new Text("Name"),
new TextFormField(
    validator: (str){
        if (str.isEmpty) {
           return "Please enter a name";
        }
    },),
```

If you want to have an alert dialog display instead of using the error text below the field, then don't use the `validator` in each TextFormField nor the `form.validate()`. A problem you have for this approach is that you are not capturing any of the TextFormField inputs. To do so, you can either use the `onSaved` property or assign a GlobalKey to each TextFormField. I'll show the onSaved method:

```
new TextFormField(
    onSaved: (value){
        setState(() {
           _name = value
        });
    },),
```

Now that you have the values set in your state variables, you can change `pressed()` to something like this:

```
pressed() {
  var form = formkey.currentState;
  form.save(); //Calling form.save() in turns calls all TextFormField's onSaved function
  var errorMsg = ""
  if (_name.isEmpty) {
     errorMsg += "Name is empty\n";
  }
  if (_last.isEmpty) {
     errorMsg += "Last is empty\n";
  }
  if (_add.isEmpty) {
     errorMsg += "Add is empty";
  }

  //Print debug if errorMsg is not empty
  if (!errorMsg.isEmpty) (
     debugPrint(errorMsg);
  }
}
```